# Highlight dates between two others in datepicker

Tags: javascript, php, datepicker

I have a javascript function which I found on SO:

```
    jQuery(function($) {

    var dates = {
    '2016-7-11': 'some description',
    '2016-7-13': 'some other description'
    };



    $('#datepicker1').datepicker({

        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var search = date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate();

            if (search in dates) {
                return [false, 'red', (dates[search] || '')];
            }

            return [true, '', ''];
        }
    });
});
```

The function should highlight all the dates between the selected, not only the selected(as it does now - I know that the if statement does exactly that). I also want it to be json string as the dates are comming from DB. I was thinking ajax but so far I don't have any luck. My ajax is not even returning the json string.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    url : '<?=BASE_URL?>date.php',
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(response){
            //alert('json returned');
            console.log(response);
        }
});
});
```

I saw a lot of answers and tutorials but I'm new to javascript/ajax and I'm little bit confused how to do it(and most of them weren't answered). Can sameone at least help me with the range problem and how to implement the ajax function into the datepicker one. I'll find the problem with the json.